# Read from Java Socket until user gets asked for input

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

How can I read from a server using Java Sockets until I am asked to send something back?
What basically happens is that when connecting to the server, the server sends a message of unknown length and after having sent it, the server asks the user for some input. This process repeats itself.

I have the following

```
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numRead;

        while ((numRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != 0) {
            System.out.println(new String(buffer));
            buffer = new byte[1024];
        }
```

However, the while loop does not stop when the user is asked for some input to send.

Comment: You need to design a protocol. Some common way of letting both parties know who should be sending data and how much. A synthetic example would be the server sending an `int N` indicating the amount of bytes the server is going to send before waiting for some kind of response from the client, then sending `N` bytes and waiting for a response.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not controlling the server.

Comment: Then the server already has a protocol it adheres to, and you need to work with that. Servers don't send messages of unknown lengths. You would know the length and the meaning of the data that the server is sending, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: What kind of server is it? A server that sends random data isn't a very useful server. Unless you're just proxying the traffic, you should know what's going on.